# Область пересечения ромба и прямоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Известны вершины ромба и прямоугольника. Какой наиболее простой и эффективный способ нахождения области их пересечения(координат вершин фигуры, которая одновременно принадлежит и ромбу и прямоугольнику)?
Ромб и прямоугольник всегда имеют такую ориентацию, меняются только их размеры и расположение на плоскости(надеюсь, правильно выразился). 

[image]

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под областью пересечения? Нужны координаты вершин фигуры, которая одновременно принадлежит и ромбу и прямоугольнику?

Comment: Да, нужны координаты вершин

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для нахождения пересечения произвольных *выпуклых* многоугольников, особенно если один из них является осеориентированным прямоугольником, прекрасно работает [алгоритм последовательного отсечения](http://algolist.manual.ru/graphics/clip_poly.php) ([Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm)).

Вы просто выбираете один из многоугольников в качестве отсекаемого, а затем в цикле последовательно "отрезаете от него все лишнее" прямыми, содержащими стороны второго (отсекающего) многоугольника. В вашем случае естественным решением будет выбрать именно *прямоугольник* в качестве отсекающего: отсечение горизонтальными и вертикальными прямыми выполняется тривиальным образом.

Answer (score 3):

Результат может быть выпуклым многоугольником с количеством вершин от 0 до 8. Чтобы не анализировать все возможные случаи, можно использовать общий алгоритм пересечения выпуклых многоугольников O'Rourke из книги Computational Geometry in C.

[Здесь](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ftp.html) есть ссылка на исходники. Результат - последовательность вершин в порядке обхода.

Если вероятность пересечения невелика, то вначале стоит проверить сам факт пересечения (например, с помощью SAT - метода separating axes)